# Android Tabs: Tabhost initialize a few tabs in one time?

Tags: android

I have a strange situation when my app runs and display tabs with inner listview. The problem is that the data for different tabs loads in one time. But It should be look like loading data only for current tab, not for all or part of tabs. Why it happens?

My main activity where is tabs creation and initialization:
    public class MainActivity extends SherlockFragmentActivity {
    TabHost mTabHost;
    ViewPager mViewPager;
    TabsAdapter mTabsAdapter;
    Bundle excercises, stretching, warmUp, lowerBody;

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
setTheme(R.style.Theme_Sherlock); // Used for theme switching in samples
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

setContentView(R.layout.home);
mTabHost = (TabHost) findViewById(android.R.id.tabhost);
mTabHost.setup();

mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);

mTabsAdapter = new TabsAdapter(this, mTabHost, mViewPager);

excercises = new Bundle();
excercises.putString("category", "Android Application Development Tutorials");
mTabsAdapter.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("Excercises").setIndicator("Excercises"),   VideoListLoader.VideoListFragment.class, excercises);

    stretching = new Bundle();
    stretching.putString("category", "iPhone Development Tutorials");
mTabsAdapter.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("Stretching").setIndicator("Stretching"), VideoListLoader.VideoListFragment.class, stretching);

    warmUp = new Bundle();
    warmUp.putString("category", "PHP Tutorials Playlist");
mTabsAdapter.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("Warm Up").setIndicator("Warm Up"), VideoListLoader.VideoListFragment.class, warmUp);

    lowerBody = new Bundle();
    lowerBody.putString("category", "Algebra Tutorials Playlist");
mTabsAdapter.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("Lower Body").setIndicator("Lower Body"), VideoListLoader.VideoListFragment.class, lowerBody);

if (savedInstanceState != null) {
    mTabHost.setCurrentTabByTag(savedInstanceState.getString("tab"));
}
}

@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
outState.putString("tab", mTabHost.getCurrentTabTag());
}

/**
 * This is a helper class that implements the management of tabs and all
 * details of connecting a ViewPager with associated TabHost. It relies on a
 * trick. Normally a tab host has a simple API for supplying a View or
 * Intent that each tab will show. This is not sufficient for switching
 * between pages. So instead we make the content part of the tab host 0dp
 * high (it is not shown) and the TabsAdapter supplies its own dummy view to
 * show as the tab content. It listens to changes in tabs, and takes care of
 * switch to the correct paged in the ViewPager whenever the selected tab
 * changes.
 */
public static class TabsAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter implements    TabHost.OnTabChangeListener, ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener {
private final Context mContext;
private final TabHost mTabHost;
private final ViewPager mViewPager;
private final ArrayList<TabInfo> mTabs = new ArrayList<TabInfo>();

static final class TabInfo {
    private final String tag;
    private final Class<?> clss;
    private final Bundle args;

    TabInfo(String _tag, Class<?> _class, Bundle _args) {
    tag = _tag;
    clss = _class;
    args = _args;
    }
}

static class DummyTabFactory implements TabHost.TabContentFactory {
    private final Context mContext;

    public DummyTabFactory(Context context) {
    mContext = context;
    }

    @Override
    public View createTabContent(String tag) {
    View v = new View(mContext);
    v.setMinimumWidth(0);
    v.setMinimumHeight(0);
    return v;
    }
}

public TabsAdapter(FragmentActivity activity, TabHost tabHost, ViewPager pager) {
    super(activity.getSupportFragmentManager());
    mContext = activity;
    mTabHost = tabHost;
    mViewPager = pager;
    mTabHost.setOnTabChangedListener(this);
    mViewPager.setAdapter(this);
    mViewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(this);
}

public void addTab(TabHost.TabSpec tabSpec, Class<?> clss, Bundle args) {
    tabSpec.setContent(new DummyTabFactory(mContext));
    String tag = tabSpec.getTag();

    TabInfo info = new TabInfo(tag, clss, args);
    mTabs.add(info);
    mTabHost.addTab(tabSpec);
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return mTabs.size();
}

@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
    TabInfo info = mTabs.get(position);
    return Fragment.instantiate(mContext, info.clss.getName(), info.args);
}

@Override
public void onTabChanged(String tabId) {
    int position = mTabHost.getCurrentTab();
    mViewPager.setCurrentItem(position);
}

@Override
public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int   positionOffsetPixels) {
}

@Override
public void onPageSelected(int position) {
    // Unfortunately when TabHost changes the current tab, it kindly
    // also takes care of putting focus on it when not in touch mode.
    // The jerk.
    // This hack tries to prevent this from pulling focus out of our
    // ViewPager.
    TabWidget widget = mTabHost.getTabWidget();
    int oldFocusability = widget.getDescendantFocusability();
    widget.setDescendantFocusability(ViewGroup.FOCUS_BLOCK_DESCENDANTS);
    mTabHost.setCurrentTab(position);
    widget.setDescendantFocusability(oldFocusability);
}

@Override
public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {
}
}
```

}

My VideoListLoader:
    public class VideoListLoader extends SherlockFragmentActivity {

```
private static final String TAG = VideoListLoader.class.getName();
VideoListFragment list;
VideoListAdapter mAdapter;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();

// Create the list fragment and add it as our sole content.
if (fm.findFragmentById(android.R.id.content) == null) {
    list = new VideoListFragment();
    fm.beginTransaction().add(android.R.id.content, list).commit();
}
}

public static class VideoListFragment extends SherlockListFragment implements   LoaderCallbacks<RESTLoader.RESTResponse>, OnItemClickListener, OnScrollListener {

private static final int LOADER_PLAYLIST_SEARCH = 0x1, LOADER_VIDEOS_SEARCH = 0x2;
VideoListAdapter mAdapter;
private static final String ARGS_URI = "net.neilgoodman.android.restloadertutorial.ARGS_URI";
private static final String ARGS_PARAMS = "net.neilgoodman.android.restloadertutorial.ARGS_PARAMS";
private static final String MAX_RESULTS = "30";
private int START_INDEX;
List<VideoEntry> playlists;
private String playlistID, category;

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

    mAdapter = new VideoListAdapter(getSherlockActivity());
    setListAdapter(mAdapter);
    mAdapter.clear();
    setListShown(false);
    getListView().setOnItemClickListener(this);
    getListView().setOnScrollListener(this);

    if (savedInstanceState != null) {
    ParseVideoList pvl = savedInstanceState.getParcelable("list");
    Log.e("Saved item: ", pvl.getArrList().get(2).getTitle());
    playlists = pvl.getArrList();
    mAdapter.setData(playlists);

    if (isResumed()) {
        setListShown(true);
    } else {
        setListShownNoAnimation(true);
    }
    } else {
    Uri playlistSearchUri =   Uri.parse("https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/thenewboston/playlists");

    Bundle params = new Bundle();
    params.putString("max-results", "50");
    params.putString("alt", "jsonc");
    params.putString("v", "2");

    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putParcelable(ARGS_URI, playlistSearchUri);
    args.putParcelable(ARGS_PARAMS, params);

    getLoaderManager().initLoader(LOADER_PLAYLIST_SEARCH, args, this);

    }
}

@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {

    ParseVideoList pvl = new ParseVideoList();
    pvl.setArrList(playlists);
    outState.putParcelable("list", pvl);
}

@Override
public Loader<RESTLoader.RESTResponse> onCreateLoader(int id, Bundle args) {
    if (args != null && args.containsKey(ARGS_URI) &&  args.containsKey(ARGS_PARAMS)) {
    Uri action = args.getParcelable(ARGS_URI);
    Bundle params = args.getParcelable(ARGS_PARAMS);

    return new RESTLoader(getSherlockActivity(), RESTLoader.HTTPVerb.GET, action, params);
    }

    return null;
}

@Override
public void onLoadFinished(Loader<RESTLoader.RESTResponse> loader, RESTLoader.RESTResponse data) {
    int code = data.getCode();
    String json = data.getData();
```

//      category = getSherlockActivity().getIntent().getExtras().getString("category");
        category = getArguments().get("category").toString();
        Log.e("Current Category: ", category);
        Log.e("JSON: ", json);
        switch (loader.getId()) {
        case LOADER_PLAYLIST_SEARCH:
        if (code == 200 && !json.equals("")) {

```
        if (playlistID == null) {
        playlistID = getPlaylistID(getSherlockActivity(), category, json);
        }

        if (playlistID != null) {
        Uri videoSearchUri = Uri.parse("https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/playlists/" + playlistID);

        Bundle params = new Bundle();
        params.putString("max-results", MAX_RESULTS);
        params.putString("start-index", "1");
        params.putString("alt", "jsonc");
        params.putString("v", "2");

        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putParcelable(ARGS_URI, videoSearchUri);
        args.putParcelable(ARGS_PARAMS, params);

        getLoaderManager().initLoader(LOADER_VIDEOS_SEARCH, args, this);
        break;
        } else {
        Toast.makeText(getSherlockActivity(), "No such a playlist", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        }
    }
    break;
    case LOADER_VIDEOS_SEARCH:
    if (code == 200 && !json.equals("")) {

        playlists = getVideoList(getSherlockActivity(), json);
        mAdapter.setData(playlists);

        if (isResumed()) {
        setListShown(true);
        } else {
        setListShownNoAnimation(true);
        }

    } else {
        Toast.makeText(getSherlockActivity(), "Failed to load data. Check your internet settings.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    break;
    }
}

@Override
public void onLoaderReset(Loader<RESTLoader.RESTResponse> loader) {
    mAdapter.setData(null);

}

private static String getPlaylistID(FragmentActivity fragmentActivity, String pCategory, String json) {
    final Context context = fragmentActivity;
    String playlistID = null;

    try {
    JSONObject playlistsWrapper = (JSONObject) new JSONTokener(json).nextValue();
    JSONArray playlists = playlistsWrapper.getJSONObject("data").getJSONArray("items");

    for (int i = 0; i < playlists.length(); i++) {
        JSONObject playlist = playlists.getJSONObject(i);
        if (pCategory.compareToIgnoreCase(playlist.getString("title")) == 0) {
        VideoEntry entry = new VideoEntry(playlist);
        entry.wrapPlaylistID(context);
        entry.wrapPlaylistTitle(context);
        playlistID = entry.getPlaylistID();
        break;
        }
    }
    } catch (JSONException e) {
    Log.e(TAG, "Failed to parse JSON.", e);
    }

    return playlistID;
}

private static List<VideoEntry> getVideoList(FragmentActivity fragmentActivity, String json) {

    List<VideoEntry> playlistsList = new ArrayList<VideoEntry>();
    final Context context = fragmentActivity;

    try {
    JSONObject playlistsWrapper = (JSONObject) new JSONTokener(json).nextValue();
    JSONArray playlists = playlistsWrapper.getJSONObject("data").getJSONArray("items");
    for (int i = 0; i < playlists.length(); i++) {
        JSONObject playlist = playlists.getJSONObject(i);
        VideoEntry entry = new VideoEntry(playlist);
        entry.wrapID(context);
        entry.wrapTitle(context);
        entry.wrapThumbURL(context);
        playlistsList.add(entry);
        Log.e("PlaylistsList: ", playlistsList.get(i).getThumbURL());
    }
    } catch (JSONException e) {
    Log.e(TAG, "Failed to parse JSON.", e);
    }

    return playlistsList;
}

@Override
public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem, int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    int last_pos = view.getLastVisiblePosition() + 10;
    Log.e("Last_pos in onScroll: ", Integer.toString(last_pos));
    if (last_pos == mAdapter.getCount() && last_pos >= Integer.valueOf(MAX_RESULTS)) {
    START_INDEX = last_pos + 1;
    Log.e("PID in onScroll:", playlistID);
    Log.e("START_INDEX in onScroll:", Integer.toString(START_INDEX));

    Uri videoSearchUri = Uri.parse("https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/playlists/" + playlistID);

    Bundle params = new Bundle();
    params.putString("max-results", MAX_RESULTS);
    params.putString("start-index", Integer.toString(START_INDEX));
    params.putString("alt", "jsonc");
    params.putString("v", "2");

    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putParcelable(ARGS_URI, videoSearchUri);
    args.putParcelable(ARGS_PARAMS, params);

    getLoaderManager().restartLoader(LOADER_VIDEOS_SEARCH, args, this);
    }
}

@Override
public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, int scrollState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
    // Intent lVideoIntent = new Intent(null, Uri.parse("ytv://" +
    // mAdapter.getItem(position).getVideoID()), getSherlockActivity(),
    // OpenYouTubePlayerActivity.class);
    // startActivity(lVideoIntent);
    new VideoManager().DownloadFromUrl("https://www.dropbox.com/s/4ph6ibvqn3e5wzq/movie.mp4", "movie.mp4");
}
}
```

}

My Log:

```
10-15 12:39:38.668: E/Current Category:(2397): Android Application Development       Tutorials
10-15 12:39:38.673: E/JSON:(2397): {"apiVersion":"2.1","data":{"totalItems":54,"startIndex":1,"itemsPerPage":50,"items":blablabla ...........

10-15 12:39:39.873: E/Current Category:(2397): Android Application Development Tutorials
10-15 12:39:39.873: E/JSON:(2397): {"apiVersion":"2.1","data":{"id":"PL2F07DBCDCC01493A","author":"thenewboston","title":"blablabla ............

10-15 12:39:41.003: E/Current Category:(2397): iPhone Development Tutorials
10-15 12:39:41.008: E/JSON:(2397): {"apiVersion":"2.1","data":{"totalItems":54,"startIndex":1,"itemsPerPage":50,"items":[{"id":blalblabla ...................

10-15 12:39:42.243: E/Current Category:(2397): iPhone Development Tutorials
10-15 12:39:42.243: E/JSON:(2397): {"apiVersion":"2.1","data":  {"id":"PL53038489615793F7","author":"thenewboston","title":"iPhone Development Tutorials","blalbla ..........
```

Here you can see loading data for 2 tabs but I didn`t switch to another tabs, only wait when first tab load what is necessary but it loads for one and second tab. Could someone explain me why it happens and how to avoid it?

Answer (score 0):

By default the `ViewPager` loads the current page and the one directly to the left and the right. This is done so you can swipe the pages smoothly.

If you don't want this to happen, you should not use `ViewPager` (or override its functionality). If you do want to use `ViewPager`, you could put your fragment logic in `onPageSelected()` or do your logic inside the parent activity. The last of these options is probably best.

Also,

> Note this class is currently under early design and development. The
>   API will likely change in later updates of the compatibility library,
>   requiring changes to the source code of apps when they are compiled
>   against the newer version.

I had some problems with the sample code myself.

Answer (score 0):

First, in order to call mTabHost.setCurrentTabByTag(YOUR_TAG), and there must be a certain delay between each tab you switch. But this is not a good practice, anybody has a better idea?